# Refresh application when code changes on nestjs

Tags: nestjs

What I want is simply refresh/reload the application when some change is made on the code. For now, I have to stop the server (ctrl + c on the terminal) and then run it again so the changes have any effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nest has a watch mode for this. Simply run `npm run start:dev` and nest will react to any change